# vb.net process start & stop

Tags: vb.net

How can I create a process out of the below code so that I can tell when it starts & finishes?

Thanks in advance :)

```
Public Shared Function EmptyDirectory(ByVal mydir As String)
    Try

        'delete all directories
        Dim myFolder As String
        For Each myFolder In Directory.GetDirectories(mydir)
            Directory.Delete(myFolder, True)
        Next

        'delete all files
        Dim myFile As String
        For Each myFile In Directory.GetFiles(mydir)
            File.Delete(myFile)
        Next

    Catch Ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return False

End Function
```

FYI: This is what I thought would work:

```
            Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            myProcess.Start(EmptyDirectory(DestDir))
            Dim ClearDirectoryStartDateTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("d") & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
            StatusBoxName.Items.Add(ClearDirectoryStartDateTime & " - Cleaning")
            ' Wait until it ends.
            myProcess.WaitForExit()
            ' Close the process to free resources.
            myProcess.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use threading. There's an interesting article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289178(v=vs.71).aspx